# Search for repositories out there with a package

Tags: repository, xscreensaver, solus

I just installed Solus.  Its repositories are somewhat limited.  I'm interested in adding a supplemental repository.  But I don't know which one would be a good one.

So let's say I want to find out what repositories out there have a particular software, let's say xscreeensaver.  I don't want to add a repository that just has xscreensaver, there are some of those out there.  I want to add a fairly large repository that includes xscreensaver.  Are there any places one can search for repositories by package?  I've found a couple sites with lists of repositories, but they're in alphabetical order and do not allow searching by package.

Perhaps this would not even work.  Perhaps the softwares on repositories for one distro do not work on unrelated distros.  Then that would answer my question as well.